# Use capslock or windows key in visual studio code

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

When using the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+             in Visual Studio Code shortcuts they do not prevent the default behavior of those keys. Is there a way to disable the default behavior of those keys in Windows, whilst still being able to use it as a shortcut.

On Linux this is simply done through

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

but I can't seem to achieve the same effect on Windows. I am fine with any of those three shortcuts, but I simply need something easy to launch the `workbench.action.showCommands` action.

Comment: CapsLock isn't a keyboard shortcut.  CapsLock sends a very specific keyboard command.  You would have to use a third-party program to have that particular button send a different command.  Likewise, the Windows key sends its own keyboard command, and third-party software would have to be used to change the command that is sent to the machine.  The only actual keyboard shortcut would be ALT+SomeOtherKey, depending on the keyboard shortcut, the shortcut can simply be changed.

Comment: @Ramhound And at least on Linux it's very easily possible to change the OS behavior of the capslock key. You need to hook into some pretty low level stuff, but it's far from impossible. And stopping windows from opening the start menu *if* a certain application is focused should be quite possible, all I don't know is which application would allow this. It's all super easy on linux, just no idea how to do it on windows.

Comment: My comment was to inform you that CapsLock isn't a keyboard shortcut.  Having built and designed a keyboard buffer I learned all about what is and isn't a keyboard shortcut fairly quickly.